# Error converting Python 2 code to Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to convert the following Python 2 code to Python 3:

```
# Consts
HEADER_SIZE = 54 # Header size of BMP
DELIMITER = "$" # Separator between number of characters and text

# User Configurations
TextToHide = "I Am Secret Information!"
ImageFile = "C:/Users/Sherif/OneDrive/P3/FW.bmp"
StegImageFile = "C:/Users/Sherif/OneDrive/P3/hidden_cat.bmp"

class LSBEncrypter(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.image_byte_counter = 0
    self.new_image_data = ''
    self.original_image = ''
    self.text_to_hide = ''

def open_image(self):
    # Open the image file
    with open(ImageFile, "rb") as f:
        self.original_image = f.read()

# Reading first chunk of the file - we don't want to overwrite the header
def read_header(self):
    for x in range(0, HEADER_SIZE):
        self.new_image_data += self.original_image[x]
        self.image_byte_counter += 1

def hide_text_size(self):
    sz = len(self.text_to_hide)
    s_sz = str(sz)
    s_sz += DELIMITER # s_sz now equal to size of text to hide + Delimiter
    self.do_steg(s_sz)

# Hides the text in the image.
# Does that by replacing the bytes LSB (Least significant bit) to be our bit
def do_steg(self, steg_text):

    # Goes through the text we want to hide, char by char
    for ch in range(0, len(steg_text)):

        current_char = steg_text[ch] # Gets current Char
        current_char_binary = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(current_char)) # Gets the binary value of current character

        # Goes through current char binary - bit by bit
        for bit in range(0, len(current_char_binary)):
            new_byte_binary = ''

            ### Overwriting the image's byte LSB with our current Bit

            # Gets the binary value of original image byte
            current_image_binary = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter]))

            # Copies the first 7 bits (we want them to be the same)
            new_byte_binary = current_image_binary[:7]

            # Set the last bit to be our bit
            new_byte_binary += current_char_binary[bit]

            # Gets the new char value by it's binary
            new_byte = chr(int(new_byte_binary, 2))

            # Adds new byte to output
            self.new_image_data += new_byte
            self.image_byte_counter += 1

def copy_rest(self):
    # Copies the what's left of the file
    self.new_image_data += self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter:]

def close_file(self):
    with open(StegImageFile, "wb") as out:
        out.write(self.new_image_data)

def run(self, stega_text):
    self.text_to_hide = stega_text
    self.open_image()
    self.read_header()
    self.hide_text_size()
    self.do_steg(self.text_to_hide)
    self.copy_rest()
    self.close_file()

def main():
    global TextToHide
    stega_instance = LSBEncrypter()
    stega_instance.run(TextToHide)
    print ("Successfully finished hiding text")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error, however:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 93, in 
>       main()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 89, in main
>       stega_instance.run(TextToHide)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 80, in run
>       self.read_header()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 28, in read_header
>       self.new_image_data += self.original_image[x] TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

So I changed:

```
def read_header(self):
    for x in range(0, HEADER_SIZE):
        self.new_image_data += str(self.original_image[x])
        self.image_byte_counter += 1
```

But get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 93, in 
>       main()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 89, in main
>       stega_instance.run(TextToHide)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 81, in run
>       self.hide_text_size()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 35, in hide_text_size
>       self.do_steg(s_sz)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 54, in do_steg
>       current_image_binary = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter]))
>   TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

So I removed 0rd():

```
def do_steg(self, steg_text):
    for ch in range(0, len(steg_text)):
        current_char = steg_text[ch] 
        current_char_binary = '{0:08b}'.format((current_char))
```

And get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 104, in 
>       main()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 100, in main
>       stega_instance.run(TextToHide)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 92, in run
>       self.hide_text_size()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 35, in hide_text_size
>       self.do_steg(s_sz)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 55, in do_steg
>       current_char_binary = '{0:08b}'.format((current_char)) # Gets the binary value of current character ValueError: Unknown format code 'b'
>   for object of type 'str'

I tried converting all functions to byte:

```
def do_steg(self, steg_text):
    for ch in range(0, len(steg_text)):

        current_char = steg_text[ch] 
        current_char_binary = '{}'.format(current_char.encode('utf-8')) # Gets the binary value of current character

        for bit in range(0, len(current_char_binary)):
            new_byte_binary = ''

            current_image_binary = '{}'.format((self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter]))

            new_byte_binary = current_image_binary[:7]

            new_byte_binary += current_char_binary[bit]

            new_byte = new_byte_binary

            self.new_image_data += new_byte
            self.image_byte_counter += 1
```

But still I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 94, in 
>       main()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 90, in main
>       stega_instance.run(TextToHide)   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 84, in run
>       self.copy_rest()   File "C:\Users\Sherif\OneDrive\P3\simple.py", line 72, in copy_rest
>       self.new_image_data += self.original_image[self.image_byte_counter:] TypeError: Can't convert
>   'bytes' object to str implicitly

How can I convert to Python 3 without these errors?

Comment: try things like `self.new_image_data = b''`. But python 3 changed a great deal all that binary stuff. Your question is too broad: fixing an error will lead to another one, ... until the program works. So better create a [mcve].

Comment: While I appreciate that you have made some attempt to fix the problem , I can  not help the feeling that you are just poking around aimlessly without trying to understand the fundamental differences between Python 2 and 3. There are many good explanations of specific differences on this site, and I suggest you search through them before continuing. As it stands, I think your question is much too broad in scope for SO.

Comment: For my peace of mind, run `2to3 -w your_program.py` and see what happens.